# jQuery if/else statement when if condition contain or (||) two variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement

I'm trying to get value of some elements and put them in one `<select>` list in `<option>` tag like:
Verify if the radio was checked and which radio is checked take section elements values and insert them with split in `<select>` as `<option>`;
In my example I have two sections/panels which can be selected through a radio input.
My problem is when I do the radio select because I use something like:

```
var scheduler = $( "#first-radio:checked" );
var cronos = $( "#second-radio:checked" );

$("#add-button").click( function() {
  if ( scheduler || cronos ) {
                              alert('None of radio options were selected!');
  } else{ 
         alert("else where my code must run"); 
  }
});
```

and normally should take else alert if one of two check box are selected when `Add val` button is pressed instead take if statement all the time and show if alert and I don't understand why :|

**[Check fiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/6809/)**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The jQuery method will always return jQuery object which will always be truthy, so your code will always execute the `if` block.

Also the checked status will change during the runtime, so you can't use a status that was fetched when the DOM was initialized - you need to check the current status of the radio buttons in the click handler.

```
var scheduler = $("#first-radio");
var cronos = $("#second-radio");

$("#add-button").click(function () {   
    if (scheduler.is(':checked') || cronos.is(':checked')) {
        alert("else where my code must run");
    } else {
        alert('None of radio options were selected!');
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/L7x6z4uy/)

Comment: what is the difference between $( "#first-radio:checked" ) and (scheduler.is(':checked') ?

Comment: $( "#first-radio:checked" ) will return an object. scheduler.is(':checked') will return a boolean.

Comment: the thing is $(SELECTOR) always returns a jQuery object even it is not there so your if condition is always true.